# Divergence of $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac 1 {n\ln2+\ln(\ln2)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Show divergence of $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac 1 {n\ln2+\ln(\ln2)}$.

Since $2>\ln  2 > \ln(\ln2)$, we have:  $\frac 1 {n\ln2+\ln(\ln2)}>\frac 1 {2(n+1)}$.

Using the comparison test: $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac 1 {2(n+1)}\overset{?}= \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac 1 {2(n)}$ we know that it diverges, therefore the given series diverges as well.

Is the part with the question mark valid (shifting the index)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac 1 {2(n+1)}= \sum^\infty_{n=3}\frac 1 {2n}$$

Easier proof:

$$  \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac 1 {n\ln2+\ln(\ln2)} \ge \frac{1}{\ln 2}\sum^\infty_{n>M}\frac{1}{n}=\infty$$

with $M = \frac{\ln(\ln 2)}{\ln 2}$

Comment: Lol, it's the other way around.

Comment: It's not easy to see it with this $M$.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I sometimes forget to accept immediately, but I always accept, even if it's after some time.